# How to flush all pipes currently running?

Tags: shell, pipe

I have some piped processes going on in the background that have been running for over a day now.

```
$ cmd | cmd | cmd | cmd | cmd > file
```

Is it possible to flush all the pipes so I can see the current state inside the file?

Comment: Worst case it should be trivial to write a wrapper around `fflush (3)`.

Comment: Don't know how to do it while they're running but, for the next time, you can use `unbuffer`. This avoid buffering between pipes. Check this link: [man unbuffer](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unbuffer1.html)

Comment: Not sure if it works, but have you tried `sync (1)`?

Comment: @Shahbaz The thing about `sync (1)` is that it calls `sync (2)`, and my manpage for it says *"The sync() function forces a write of dirty (modified) buffers in the block buffer cache out to disk."*, which leaves open the possibility that non-disk files will not be flushed.

Comment: @dmckee good to know. Still, there may be some of the data waiting to be flushed in the last `> file`. But you are right, this doesn't entirely solve the problem.

Comment: @Shahbaz After looking at several manpages I've concluded that you need *both* `fflush (3)` and `sync (2)` to make it work.The linux `fflush (3)` page says *"Note that fflush() only flushes the user space buffers provided by  the C  library.   To  ensure that the data is physically stored on disk the kernel buffers must be flushed too, e.g. with sync(2) or fsync(2)."*

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Compile

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  fflush(NULL);
  if (!errno) sync();
  return errno;
}
```

to, say, `fflush` and but it in `~/bin` or `/opt/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` depending on your personal preference and permissions, make sure this command is in your path and simply use it.

### Discussion

The fact that this (simple!) thing does not exist in the usual toolset suggests that it is rarely useful: in general this defeats attempts by the OS to be smart and makes things slow down. Worse, with an extended pipeline like the one you exhibit, it may flush the pipes in the "wrong" order leaving not much more certain of the current progress than you were before.

Comment: It may be better to remove the `if (!errno)`. If `fflush` fails mid-war for any reason, there _might_ still be data you could flush with `sync`.

Comment: I can see the use of that, but then I'll need to cache the error code and do something more sophisticated by way of error reporting. Serepo, if you are interested in seeing that let me know: I'm going to leave this as is for the moment.

Comment: Rather than making the code more sophisticated, is it possible I could just call `sync` command from the terminal and get the same effect?